# error with prestashop smarty template when adding price rule

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.6

I am getting following error when I add to catalog price rule and go to product page. when i checked the path `/var/www/Germany/cache/smarty/compile/43/` and check directory there is no directory found

> [Tue Jul 31 08:19:55.349417 2018] [:error] [pid 9379] [client
>   172.31.22.27:19804] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty: unable to write file
>   /var/www/Germany/cache/smarty/compile/43/b7/ef/wrt5b601bab5205b6_55461255
>   <-- \n  thrown in
>   /var/www/Germany/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php
>   on line 46, referer:
>   http://de.galaxykayaks.eu/admin088rkbwnk/index.php?controller=AdminProducts&id_product=34&updateproduct&token=9149fd1199969891eb153b8825d58dbb

please help me what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

First, try to disable the cache.

Second, check your permissions files/folders, because it looks like this kind of problems

Comment: We have set 777 also 755 permission files and folder But Same 500 error getting

Comment: Also checked disable all cache and try but not solved

Answer (score 0):

This issue with the wrong old version override folder smarty cache file

When I remove the old smarty cache file then its work fine.